# Writing ETW event logs

Tags: c#, powershell, etw

I need to write some ETW entries into Windows Event Log. For example, I need to generate some events in the Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/AAD (or any other folder, doesn't really matter).

`New-winevent` in powershell does exactly that, but is way too slow.

I also tried this
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/09/announcing-the-eventsource-nuget-package-write-to-the-windows-event-log/
and it generates events into any folder quickly, but I see no obvious way of generating events as existing provider. If I try to register a new one, wevtutil complains that provider for this folder is already registered (which makes sense).
So what is the best way around this?  How do you generate events as some existing provider?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with it for some time, finally figured it out in case someone faces the same problem.

I never found a way to use the existing provider. Instead, I generated manifest file and used it to uninstall existing provider:

`wevtutil.exe -um $manifestfile`

After that, the new one, the one generating events that I need, can be installed without any errors:
`wevtutil.exe -im $manifestfile /mf:$dllfile /rf:$dllfile`

Obviously, existing logs stop working if you do that.